# Can't install glibc-2.19

Tags: software-installation, glibc

Several times I tried to install the library glibc-2.19, but it always ended in an error. I followed the installation instructions but it didn't work. I'm trying to install glibc-2.19 on Ubuntu 13.10, 32 bit.

Comment: What is the error? What are the installation instructions?

Answer (score 3):

if I am not wrong **glibc** and **libc6** are same version of GNU C Library from http://www.linux-m68k.org/faq/glibcinfo.html

so you can install **libc6** instead which is available in ubuntu 14.04 and 13.10 also

```
sudo apt-get install libc6
```

Answer (score 0):

[Eglibc](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/trusty/eglibc) is the glibc application in ubuntu :

It is build from following packages and so install following packages :

```
sudo apt-get install eglibc-source glibc-doc libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6-amd64 libc6-dbg libc6-dev libc6-dev-amd64 libc6-dev-i386 libc6-dev-x32 libc6-i386 libc6-pic libc6-prof libc6-udeb libc6-x32 libnss-dns-udeb libnss-files-udeb multiarch-support nscd
```